# ¿Cómo se ordena una matriz en C++?

Tags: c++

Quiero ordenar una matriz en *C++*. El criterio es en *zig-zag* (como el juego de la viborita), el menor debe quedar abajo a la derecha, luego sube y baja sin parar hasta llegar a la izquierda arriba.

Lo siguiente es un ejemplo de 3x3, pero quiero que funcione para dimensiones variadas.

```
 8   3  11                   (fin) 22   5 < 4
                                    ^   v   ^
 4   1   7 "Debería quedar así" -> 11   7   3
                                    ^   v   ^
22   9   5                          9 < 8   1 (principio)
```

Código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numeros[100][100],filas,columnas;

    cout<<"Digite el numero de filas: "; cin>>filas;
    cout<<"Digite el numero de columnas: "; cin>>columnas;

    //Rellenando la matriz  
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<"Digite un numero ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
            cin>>numeros[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"\nMostrando matriz\n\n";

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<numeros[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: solo necesito ayuda, hay esta el codigo no veo el problema, si no quieren ayudar pues no lo hagan no tienen porque quitarla ArtEze?

Comment: no lo pude hacer !! intente editar y me enviaba a otra parte ! mi ultima alternativa fue publicar de nuevo de una manera mas completa !.

Comment: Anthony Gelvez, la pregunta que haces es demasiado amplia, y si la se respondiese con el código que resuelve ese ejercicio, por una parte, tú no aprenderías adecuadamente y por otra, la comunidad no funcionaría bien, el esfuerzo debe de ser mutuo.

Así que voy a darte una idea para ayudarte, y el código intenta ponerlo tú: Piensa cómo debe de quedar la matriz final. Debes hacer un recorrido de la matriz en ese sentido, y los recorridos se hacen con bucles... Luego cada elemento que coloques en cada posición debe de cumplir ciertas condiciones, las que te pide el ejercicio...

Comment: (...Continúo) La solución se resume en ese bucle. Ahora te toca a tí poner de tu parte, comerte la cabeza y una de dos: o responder a esta pregunta con el código de la solución, o editar la pregunta escribiendo el código que has pensado y te has trabajado, y a partir de ahí ya veremos.

Comment: @Miguelw aunque efectivamente sea un comentario, si el mismo no es legible puedes simplemente empezar la respuesta con algo tipo "_se que esto es un comentario, pero debido a su longitud / si lo pongo como tal no es legible y blablabla_"

Comment: @eferion Entiendo, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez

Comment: @Miguelw aun así úsalo solo en casos estrictamente necesarios y no olvides borrar el comentario/pregunta cuando ya no sea necesario. No hay que olvidar que es una estrategia que perjudica la legibilidad de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

¡Con mucha ayuda pues lo logré! por hay me dieron una pista de usar un bucle gracias por eso.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int filas();
int columnas();
int llenar();
int mostraro();
int burbuja();
int zigzag();
int mostrarz();
int f,c,mayor=0,i,j,cont=0,aux,inv,x,y;
int ma[10][10], mat[10];
int mataux [10][10];


int main()
{

filas();
columnas();
llenar();
mostraro();
burbuja();
zigzag();
mostrarz();
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}


int filas(){
    cout<<"Intruduzca el numero de Fila:";
    cin>>f;
return 0;}

int columnas(){
     cout<<"Intruduzca el numero de Columna:";
    cin>>c;
return 0;}

int llenar(){
        cout<<"Matriz ("<<f<<","<<c<<")."<<endl;
    for(int i=1; i<=f; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=c; j++)
        {
             cout<<"introducir datos ("<<i<<","<<j<<"):";
             cin>>ma[i][j];
        }
    }
cout<<endl;
return 0;}
int mostraro(){
    cout<<"Los Datos De La Matriz son:"<<endl;
    for(int i=1; i<=f; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=c; j++)
        {
            cout<<ma[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;}
int burbuja(){
     for(i=1; i<=f; i++){
        for(j=1; j<=c; j++){
            for(x=1; x<=f;x++){
                for(y=1; y<=c; y++){
                    if(ma[i][j]<ma[x][y]){
                        mayor=ma[i][j];
                        ma[i][j]=ma[x][y];
                        ma[x][y]=mayor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }

return 0;}
int zigzag(){
    cout<<"Los Datos De La Matriz Fueron Ordenados de menor a mayor en zigzag vertical"<<endl;

if (c%2==0) {

    int conte=0;

for(i=1; i<=f; i++)
    {
        conte=conte%2;
        cout<<endl;

        for(j=1; j<=c; j++)
        {
                if (conte==1)
                {

                    mataux[i][j]=ma[i][j];
                    }

                if (conte==0){

                            for(x=1; x<=c; x++){
                                mat[x]=ma[i][c-x+1];
                            }
                            mataux[i][j]=mat[j];
                }
        }
        conte=i;

    }
    }



if (c%2!=0) {

    int conta=-1;

    for(int i=1; i<=f; i++)
    {

        for(int j=1; j<=c; j++)
        {

                conta=i;
                conta=conta%2;

                if (conta==1){

                            for(x=1; x<=c; x++){
                                mat[x]=ma[i][c-x+1];
                            }
                            mataux[i][j]=mat[j];
                }


                if (conta==0){

                    mataux[i][j]=ma[i][j];
                    }
        }
    }

    }
return 0;}

int mostrarz(){
     for(i=1; i<=f; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=c; j++)
        {
            cout<<mataux[j][i]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pidieron ayuda para ordenar los datos de una matriz de mayor a menor.

Así que les dejo el código de como lo hice talvez les sirve a alguien mas.


/***************************************************
   Ordenar Los Datos de una Matriz de Mayor a Menor

   Hecho por ANONIMO*****

****************************************************/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int f=2,c=2,mayor=0;
     int matriz[f][c];
     //lleno la matriz
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
             cout<<"introducir datos:";
             cin>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    //imprimo la matriz como se lleno
    cout<<"\nLos Datos De La Matriz Fuero Introducidos Asi"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            cout<<matriz[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

     //ordeno la matriz de mayor a menor
     for(int i=0; i<f; i++)
     {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<f;x++)
            {
                for(int y=0; y<c; y++)
                {
                    if(matriz[i][j]>matriz[x][y])
                    {
                        mayor=matriz[i][j];
                        matriz[i][j]=matriz[x][y];
                        matriz[x][y]=mayor;
                    }

                }
            }
         }
    }

    //imprimo la matriz como ordenada
    cout<<"\nLos Datos De La Matriz Fueron Ordenados de Mayor a Menor"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            cout<<matriz[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Lo hice con una matriz de 2*2 pero puede funcionar con el numero de columnas y filas que uno quiera solo es de cambiar la declaración de la matriz o pedir al usuario el numero de filas y columnas.

Linea 17 a 24 lleno la matriz.
Linea 27 a 34 imprimo la matriz como se lleno.
Linea 37 a 55 ordeno la matriz lo que hice aquí es implementar el conocido método de la burbuja el cual consiste en ir comparando los datos en este caso de mayor a menor y los va ordenando.
Linea 59 a 66 imprimo nuevamente la matriz solo que esta vez ya esta ordenada.
```